# why function "host" gives different results when using IP instead of domain name?

Tags: dns, kali-linux

I'm learning DNS, and when using the "host" bash function on Kali, i get different results according that i give the IP adress or its domain name equivalent:

```
host -t ns axis.com
   => 81.68.60.195.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer sherlock01.se.axis.com

host -t ns 195.60.68.81
   => axis.com name server nic2.axis.com.
      axis.com name server nic.axis.com.
      axis.com name server nic4.axis.com.
      axis.com name server nic3.axis.com.
```

Why is it so ?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First output is the `PTR` record for the domain `axis.com`

Second one means that server on ip `195.60.68.81` has 4 `NS` records:

```
  axis.com name server nic2.axis.com.
  axis.com name server nic.axis.com.
  axis.com name server nic4.axis.com.
  axis.com name server nic3.axis.com.
```

Meaning that domain `axis.com` can be resolved using one of those 4 servers